# How to convert existing Java project to JavaFX project on NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, javafx-2, javafx, netbeans-7

I have a regular Java project on NetBeans 7.2.1 and I want to convert it to JavaFX project. Is there an automatic way to do that or do I have to create a new project and import my sources to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no conversion utility in NetBeans 7.2.1 to make a regular NetBeans java project into a JavaFX project - create a new JavaFX project and import your old sources into it.