# How to convert existing Java project to JavaFXML in Netbeans

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I've seen some answers ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202740/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-javafx-project-on-netbeans)) - converting is not possible. But it is few years old. Is there any way of converting JavaFX/FXML project from existing Java project in Netbeans now?

If not, i guess make new JavaFXML project is the only way. But how do i import this existing project there? Simply copy-paste/refractor files?

Comment: I’d go for the second option, but maybe use a Maven structure to provide a less coupled solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am just amateur and not familiar with Maven (it is in my learning TO-DO list). So I have no idea what you mean by this. As the second option - could I just refractor existing files to my new javaFXML project?

Comment: I depends, is you're existing project already in netbeans? Netbeans has it's own project format, normally, you can just drag and drop (or import) existing files into a project and they should be refactored in place...mostly

Comment: Existing project is already in Netbeans. I make new JavaXML project in Netbeans and now i though about this: both projects are in Netbeans. So i drag & copy existing files/folders into new one and it shoud be okey, or not?

Comment: Since they are both in netbeans, you can make one a dependency  of the other via the projects “library” support